# How to prevent removal of special characters like '/' from user input?

Tags: php, url, path

A total newbie question....

I am developing a Joomla template and in this I want to make provision to load the assets (Images, JavaScript and CSS) from a remote location or locally.

I am using the following code for the same:

```
<?php

class MyclassName {

function CDNPath(){
return $this->getParam("cdn-path","templates/myTemplate/cdn");
}

}
?>
```

Now in this I want to call the value for `$cdn_path` via user-input. I am able to get the path but it is removing the `'/'` marks. Please see the example below:

The correct path to CDN is `http://mydomain.com/cdn`

It is suppose to read as:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/joomla/http://mydomain.com/cdn/css/template.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

whereas it is reading as:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/joomla/http:mydomain.comcdn/css/template.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

The breakup for this `joomla` is the root directory of joomla and  `http://mydomain.com/cdn/`  is the user input

Two challenges:

1. it is removing all the `'/'` characters from the user-input.
2. It is adding the Joomla Root `'joomla'` to the begining of the path.

Am I coding wrong? If yes then what is the correct syntax.

**Please feel free to suggest any new approach if you feel will be better than this.**

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried url encoding the user input?

Comment: Hi @Naatan thanks for the post but actually no I did not try doing it as I am totally a newbie to programming and don't know how to do it. I am still in the learning stage. However there is a second challenge also to my issue where it is adding the Joomla's root directory at the beginning of user-input.

Comment: @Naatan also that this variable will be a user input via the `templateDetails.xml` file. So it may not be possible for a user to input encoded URL.

Comment: How does the input end up in the resulting html page? You will need some form of control over this. If you cant then you could make a proxy script located in the root of your joomla directory which would take your user input as the url to proxy. By no means a good solution but a solution never the less.

Comment: Hmmm... I am not sure about that. May be some Joomla expert will be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the input via post (im not sure how you are taking input from user. ) 
so you can try something like this to add slashes :

```
<?php
//create array to temporarily grab variables
$input_arr = array();
//grabs the $_POST variables and adds slashes
foreach ($_POST as $key => $input_arr) {
$_POST[$key] = addslashes($input_arr);
}
?>
```

if its array..

Comment: Hi @Ayaz thanks for helping. I am using Joomla so the input is taken via the `templateDetails.xml` file in XML format. Example : `<param name="cdn-path" type="text" default="templates/myTemplate/cdn/" size="50" label="Path to your CDN" description="Path to your CDN" />`

Comment: since im haven't tried joomla i can't suggest you much, i did a little research and found this .. give it a try but with a backup of your file ofcourse :) 

For a workaround, you can fix by modifying cb.core.php

at line cb.core.php:99 (cb 1.1)

modify sefRelToAbs($uimage)
to sefRelToAbs('/'.$uimage)